# How to understand this sentence (underlining blue), especially "the" and "that so"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Machiavelli "The Prince" Chapter VIII

The Harvard Classics:

> Injuries, therefore, should be inflicted all at once, that their ill savour being less lasting may **the** less offend; whereas, benefits should be conferred little by little, **that so** they may be more fully relished.

I'm wondering:

1 "the" should either be deleted, or be corrected as "they" ("may they" is the inversion of "they may").

2 "that so" should be "so that" or "that".

FYI (the Harvard Classics is the last one of the four translations):
[image]

Comment: In **the less** and **the more** the word **the** is the survival of an archaic instrumental inflection.  **the less|the more** = to a lesser |greater degree

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about obsolete or archaic English are off topic.

Comment: @JamesK The Harvard Classics translation was in 1909.

Comment: It's still not a form that would be used now. Now we would say "Offend less" and "so" instead of "that so". The source text is very hard to understand, even for native speakers. I've found examples of the "that so" in the KJV of the bible and in some victorian texts.  It isn't a form used in modern English

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Is "*the*" in "the less offend" an adverb just as in "so much the better/worse" ?

Comment: Little Red Riding Hood says to the wolf, "Grandma, why do you have such big eyes?"  and the wolf replies, "The better to see you, my dear."

Comment: In Old English, **þȳ**,was the instrumental case of the pronoun **se** but in that oblique case the pronoun expressed degree ("by *that much*").   And by "Old English" I don't mean the English of 100 years ago but the English of over 1000 years ago.

Comment: @JamesK Yes, "The Prince" is very hard even for ITALIAN natives. However, I should and will comprehend it. So I'm referring a detailed Italian map, FIVE translations (mainly the former three, including a Chinese version; occasionally the latter two, the one of which is the Harvard Classics while the other of which didn't show in the question) and Wikipedia. To understand those English materials, I desperately need your help. I had no idea that a 1909's translation used archaic English. Fortunately, I don't choose it as one of the main reference books.

Comment: It's not itself archaic, but is the vestige of an ancient form. Language changes over time.  We use this construction all the time.  "He likes it all the better if it has a few dings and dents".  *Because it was forbidden, they wanted to do it all the more.*